# Zoom in on image on hover using transform: scale, still making image bigger from outside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make it so the image zooms in on itself with out making the outside larger e.g this is what I want, I have tried to implement this but it doesn't work the same: http://jsfiddle.net/7vY7v/130/. What am I doing wrong?

I am using bootstrap, and using the `img-responsive` class on the imgs aswell.

Heres my demo of what I have done so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJzexN

Code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 img-wrapper">

                        <img src="https://unsplash.it/800" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/800" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pushdown"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/800" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/800" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="people">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-wrapper img:hover {
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your HTML structure to this:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEOzXe)

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/800" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason the element appeared to be expanding was because there is padding on the parent `.col-md-6` element (`padding-left`/`padding-right` of `15px`).

By changing the immediate parent element to `.img-wrapper`, you effectively displace this and hide the overflow.

Comment: Perfect! I thought it must of been something easy, I will accept your answer shortly :) Thank you!