# Bootstrap popup login page not working?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i am new to php framework and bootstrap working on CodeIgnitor 3.0.
I have simple navigation bar for signup and login clicking on login redirects to another page where is another login button clicking on which should open the popup
login form but it's not working??

//my nav bar

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOODP"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="<?= base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>

    body {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
</style>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                         data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">SignUp</a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('LoginController/index') ?>">Login</a></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

//login.php  in views folder

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOODP"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="<?= base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Login</a>

        <div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
            <h3>Login to MyWebsite.com</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
              <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
              <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"></p>
              <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            New To MyWebsite.com?
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should i do if i want that login page to popup on homepage???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues that you need to correct. To get the modal working you need to remove the `hide` class on the modal.

> ```
> <div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
> ```

should be

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
```

---

Also, the hyperlink should have data-target (not href). So

> ```
> <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Login</a>
> ```

should be

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a>
```

---

These changes should get the modal running, but there are other corrections you need to do

In both your files you are loading bootstap, jquery and then bootstrap again. You only need to load bootstrap once and it should be after the jQuery, So

> ```
>  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
>  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
>  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
> ```

should be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is the complete //login.php that should work (I've added body and title tags for completeness and closed the html tag)

I've also replaced the script and css with CDN versions to take out any problems with your local js files. Do swap them back once you get it working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOODP"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a>

            <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Login to MyWebsite.com</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
                        <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
                        <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"></p>
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    New To MyWebsite.com?
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Make sure your jquery and boostrap min are loading. The fiddle with the above markup seems to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/zqcrz30o/

Comment: Try copying the complete HTML given at the end of the answer (I just updated it a bit) into an HTML file and see if it works. Also make sure your js and css files are being downloaded (i.e. it's not being blocked) and that you have not disabled javascript.

Comment: Cheers! What was the problem? I mean, apart from the changes above.

Comment: i have disabled javascript and in chrome but its now working mozilla being my fav....

Comment: there is small guidence i want i am developing UI in bootstrap Which has full page slider and now that sider i want images like here in explore cities
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=site-ui&utm_campaign=multicollider
that's code above but i am failing to do so coz when i navbar img in slider deflects .... so any suggestions or link

Comment: You want the image backgrounds to zoom on hover?

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377817/zoom-in-on-image-on-hover-using-transform-scale-still-making-image-bigger-from or this - http://magnigenie.com/creating-image-zoom-effect-using-css3-transitions/

Comment: what can i do if want to display the popup on same home page instead of redirecting to other page

Comment: Just move your modal code over to the home page and change <a href="<?php echo site_url('LoginController/index') ?>">Login</a> to the daa-target one.